# Send event to websocket when NO action occurred in input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, websocket

I want to implement function to check if someone is typing (or not) in web chat application. So when someone is typing I can send event using this function:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
fromEvent(this.inputText.nativeElement, 'input')
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
  .subscribe(result => {
  this.messageBroker.sendTypingNotification(new MessageModel(null, this.author, MessageType.USER_TYPING));
})
```

}

But how to send event when there is no action (typing) in input field?

Comment: Probably a better idea to handle that serverside?

Answer (score 0):

I find out a solution. After the keyDown event delayed by 1 second occurs, I send a notification.

```
fromEvent(this.inputText.nativeElement, 'keydown')
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
  ).subscribe(() => {
    this.messageBroker.sendTypingNotification(new MessageModel(null, this.author, MessageType.USER_TYPING));
  });
```